# gradle import dependency inside buildscript

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to add use some import blocks inside buildscript?

For example if I want to implement some logic inside `buildscript` like

```
buildscript { 
    repositories {
        if (UtilClass.checkProject(project)) {
            ivy { }
        } else { maven { } }
    }
}
```

But I need to `import com.pack.project.UtilClass`, however as far as I can seen I cannot  add `import` inside `buildscript`.

Is there some workaround (without introducing additional properties)?

Comment: I assume checkProject is a static function? Why not use fully qualified name for UtilClass?

Comment: when I do `com.pack.project.UtilClass` It does not work with the error `Could not find property 'com' `

Comment: PeterN advises against doing this in the buildscript section: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-custom-classes-within-the-buildscript-block/7023